# MATLAB: fprintf complex matrix to txt file

Tags: matlab, matrix, printf, complex-numbers

Let say I have a complex matrix:

```
A = [3-3i 3.2 3.1 2.2212; 2.31-8i 9.9i 0.12i 2.23i;9.1i 9 9.999 0.12;1.2i 1.8i 8 9.0001];
```

How can I print this complex matrix into a txt file? I try:
`fprintf(fid, [repmat('%.8f\t', 1, size(A, 2)) '\n'], A');`

but it only print the real numbers.

Comment: This is one of those situations where you need to be very careful about how you transpose your data. The `'` operator is the [complex conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) (which swaps rows and columns *and* negates the imaginary parts) and the `.'` operator is the regular [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) (which simply swaps rows and columns). You **almost always** want to use `.'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output the real and imaginary parts separately like this:

```
fprintf(fid, [repmat('%.8f%+.8fi\t', 1, size(A, 2)) '\n'], ...
        [real(reshape(A.', 1, [])); imag(reshape(A.', 1, []))]);
```